# How can I use Haskell and GIO to read a file?

Tags: haskell, gtk2hs, gio

For example, here's a small piece of a program I'm writing using Haskell and gtk2hs:

```
import System.GIO

foreign import ccall safe "g_type_init"
    g_type_init :: IO ()

main :: IO ()
main = do
    g_type_init
    let file = fileFromParseName "my-file.txt"
    inputStream <- fileRead file Nothing
    ...
```

The `fileRead` method returns a `FileInputStream` instance, but I can't for the life of me find anywhere in the documentation a method to read from it. The corresponding C method in GIO should be `g_input_stream_read`, but it doesn't seem to be implemented in gtk2hs.

Am I missing something?

Comment: `g_type_init` is available [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/glib/latest/doc/html/System-Glib-GType.html#v:glibTypeInit) (not sure about the rest of the question, though).

Comment: It doesn't make sense that they would provide a way to create an input stream and not a method for reading from it.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use Haskell's standard file IO functions?

Comment: For flexibility, consistency, and curiosity. Mostly curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation I managed to write my own implementation of `g_input_stream_read`. It's not very pretty and might not even be safe, but this will successfully print the first 1,024 characters of the file specified at the top of main:

```
import Control.Monad (liftM)
import Data.Char (chr)
import Data.Word (Word8)
import Foreign
import Foreign.C (CInt)
import System.GIO
import System.GIO.Types (unInputStream, toInputStream)
import System.Glib (glibTypeInit, GError)

foreign import ccall unsafe "g_input_stream_read"
    -- inputStreamRead <stream> <buffer> <count> <cancellable> <error>, returns the number of bytes read
    inputStreamRead :: Ptr InputStream -> Ptr a -> CInt -> Ptr (Maybe Cancellable) -> Ptr GError -> IO (CInt)

addrToChar :: Ptr a -> Int -> IO (Char)
addrToChar p i = do
    let addr = p `plusPtr` i
    val <- peek addr :: IO Word8
    return $ chr (fromIntegral val)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    glibTypeInit
    let file = fileFromParseName "file.txt"
    fileInputStream <- fileRead file Nothing
    let stream = unInputStream $ toInputStream fileInputStream
    allocaBytes 1024 $ \buffer -> do
        alloca $ \err -> do
            bytesRead <- liftM fromEnum $ inputStreamRead (unsafeForeignPtrToPtr stream) buffer 1024 nullPtr err :: IO Int
            result <- mapM (addrToChar buffer) [0..bytesRead]
            putStrLn result
```

It needs some work in order to become a simple `inputStreamRead :: InputStream -> IO (String)`, but at least it's a step in the right direction.

EDIT: found a better solution. This one should keep reading until the number of bytes read equals 0, and has a friendlier entry point:

```
import Control.Monad (liftM)
import Data.Char (chr)
import Data.Word (Word8)
import Foreign
import Foreign.C (CInt)
import System.GIO
import System.GIO.Types
import System.Glib (glibTypeInit, GError)

foreign import ccall unsafe "g_input_stream_read"
    -- inputStreamRead <stream> <buffer> <count> <cancellable> <error>, returns the number of bytes read
    inputStreamRead :: Ptr InputStream -> Ptr a -> CInt -> Ptr Cancellable -> Ptr GError -> IO (CInt)

chunk :: Int
chunk = 4096

bytesToText :: [Word8] -> [Char]
bytesToText [] = []
bytesToText (x:xs) = (chr $ fromEnum x):(bytesToText xs)

readGIOStream :: InputStream -> Maybe Cancellable -> IO ([Word8])
readGIOStream stream cancel = do
    allocaBytes chunk $ \buffer -> do
        alloca $ \err -> do
            case cancel of
                Just c  -> withForeignPtr (unCancellable c) $ \c' -> readChunk buffer c' err streamPtr
                Nothing -> readChunk buffer nullPtr err streamPtr
            where streamPtr = unInputStream stream
                  readChunk b c e s = withForeignPtr s $ \s' -> do
                          bytesRead <- liftM fromEnum $ inputStreamRead s' b (toEnum chunk) c e
                          result <- mapM (\i -> peek $ b `plusPtr` i) [0..(bytesRead-1)]
                          if bytesRead == 0
                              then return result
                              else do rest <- readChunk b c e s
                                      return $ result ++ rest

main :: IO ()
main = do
    glibTypeInit
    let file = fileFromParseName "live-forever.txt"
    fileInputStream <- fileRead file Nothing
    text <- liftM bytesToText $ readGIOStream (toInputStream fileInputStream) Nothing
    putStrLn text
```